# Presenting a table retrieved through JDBC - JAVA

Tags: java, sql, jtable, jframe

As part of a learn Java project im making a simple a app that

1. Adds properties details to an SQL Database and
2. Presents the properties that have been stored through option 1.

I have the SQL setup and option 1 running fine. If i select option 1 a JFrame with options pops up. I input the details and click ok. It then stores them fine in Database.

Problem is im not sure where to even start with part 2. Is it possible to present a table in a JFrame somehow using the SQL table. I literally just want to present the whole Property table. No need to limit it down or anything. Just an easy viewing without looking through PHPMyadmin

Thanks

Comment: You can do this using `JTable` commponent.

Comment: This question is too diffuse; it will likely not generate many useful answers.  Try to focus your questions to specific programming problems involving code you're actually working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JDBC to get data from your table
Then use a Jtable in your jframe to display your data.

Read on following articles. They will help you

[Java JDBC](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdbc/index.html)

[JDBC with GUI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/jdbcswing.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is a great starting point - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html